# Displaying a php mysql result with two values with a foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have result that I want to display as a drop down menu.  The query selects id and name from a table.

```
        $usersQuery = "SELECT id, name
        FROM users";
        $usersResult = mysqli_query ($dbc, $usersQuery);
```

I want to use this result as a list in a drop down menu.  This is what i have so far.

```
      <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
        <option value="select" selected="selected">Select</option>
       <?php
        while ($usersRow = mysqli_fetch_array($usersResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
          foreach ($usersRow as $value){
            echo "<option value=\"$value\"";
            echo ">$value</option>\n";
          }
        }
        ?>
      </select>
```

this would work fine if I just wanted to display name as both the value and the display to the user. But what I want to do is use the selected id as "value" for the select option and I want to show the name selected to the user.  I have tried this but it does not work.

```
  <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
    <option value="select" selected="selected">Select</option>
   <?php
    while ($usersRow = mysqli_fetch_array($usersResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
      foreach ($usersRow as $id=>$name){
        echo "<option value=\"$id\"";
        echo ">$name</option>\n";
      }
    }
    ?>
  </select>
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to ask clear and as-short-as-possible question which go to the very core of the problem... php, mysql, foreach, ... that doesn't look like real problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_array()` is a function which converts your query results into an array. which means you can display your values like you would with a normal array value.

```
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
    <option value="select" selected="selected">Select</option>
   <?php
    while ($usersRow = mysqli_fetch_array($usersResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){


        echo "<option value=\"".$usersRow['id']."\"";
        echo ">".$usersRow['name']."</option>\n";

    }
    ?>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for the `foreach` iteration; `mysqli_fetch_array()` already provides an associative array. After each fetch do

```
// Assuming "id" is a numeric value
printf('<option value="%d">%s</option>', $usersRow['id'], $usersRow['name']);
```

Comment: It should be noted that when only associative keys are required, it is (slightly) more efficient to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` is unnecessary - using a while loop on the `mysqli_fetch_array` command will return all the results with each row in an array - you can use it like so:

```
while ($usersRow = mysqli_fetch_array($usersResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo "<option value=\"".$usersRow['id']."\"";
    echo ">".$usersRow['name']."</option>\n";
}
```